# Cycle is not printing active window

Tags: c, winapi

I have a simple cycle with simple window print function.

```
char temp[100], *currbuf= "", *currbuf2 = "";


while (1) {
    GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow(), temp, sizeof temp / sizeof *temp);
    currbuf2 = temp;
    if (currbuf2 != currbuf) {
        currbuf = temp;
        printf("\n\nWindow title: %s\n", temp);
    };
};
```

Problem is that it print only title of first active window.
What i want to do is to print title of active window everytime it changes.
Without if statement it works well(but still printing that active window).

Comment: `currbuf2` will usually never be equal to `currbuf` unless the compiler is merging duplicate string literals. However you set both of them to equal `temp`. That is not the way to compare a string in C.

Comment: This will hog your CPU.

Comment: @WeatherVane But if they never will be equal it will be printing something forever. But with that IF statement it prints only first active window.

Comment: @JurajJakubov I was editing the first comment.

Comment: Thanks i was googling and going to try "strcmp".

Comment: You don't copy strings in C with `=` and even if you used `strcpy` the target is a (read-only) string literal of inadequate size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly compare strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem is that it print only title of first active window.

You need to compare the string *contents*, not the string *pointers*:

```
char temp[100] = "", currbuf[100] = "";

while (1) {
    GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow(), temp, sizeof temp / sizeof *temp);
    if (strcmp(currbuf, temp) != 0) {
        strcpy(currbuf, temp);
        printf("\n\nWindow title: %s\n", temp);
    }
}
```

> What i want to do is to print title of active window everytime it changes.

Rather than using an endless loop that constantly polls the active window, you should instead use [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) to receive `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND` notifications from the OS whenever the foreground window changes. Don't poll (except maybe the first time before starting the hook).

```
void displayWindowTitle(HWND hWnd)
{
    char temp[100] = "";
    GetWindowText(hWnd, temp, sizeof temp / sizeof *temp);
    printf("\n\nWindow title: %s\n", temp);
}

void CALLBACK MyHookCallback(HWINEVENTHOOK hook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    displayWindowTitle(hwnd);
}

...

displayWindowTitle(GetForegroundWindow());
HWINEVENTHOOK hHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, NULL, &MyHookCallback, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
...
UnhookWinEvent(hHook);
```